# How to retrieve a file that has been added then removed in a Docker image?

Tags: docker

Assume you have a working directory like this:

```
$ tree .
.
├── Dockerfile
└── file.txt
```

And the `Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM debian:9

WORKDIR /usr/src/foo

COPY file.txt .

RUN echo Some random command involving file.txt \
  && rm -f file.txt
```

And you build and push the corresponding image to a given Docker registry:

```
$ docker build -t foo/bar .
$ docker login #…
$ docker push foo/bar
```

Is there a way (or several ways) to retrieve from the image, the contents of `file.txt` that was added then removed in an intermediate layer? Does the answer depend on the choice of the `WORKDIR`?

Comment: A comment not an answer, because I _think_ so... It's my understanding that yes there is an intermediate overlay layer with the file. However, if the `Dockerfile` uses the new [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) it might not... I'm still learning those myself!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way (or several ways) to retrieve from the image, the contents of file.txt that was added then removed in an intermediate layer?

Yes!

> Does the answer depend on the choice of the WORKDIR?

No. `WORKDIR` doesn't do anything other than change the current working directory.

---

When you build an image from a Dockerfile, each directive in the Dockerfile creates a new layer.  An "image" is just a collection of layers that are combined to form the container filesystem when you run a container.  Each of those layers can be found separately on your disk under `/var/lib/docker`.  For example, let's say I build an image using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:9
COPY file.txt /root/file.txt
RUN rm -f /root/file.txt
```

In that directory, I have a file named `file.txt` that contains the text:

```
hello world
```

If I run `docker build -t erikmd .`, I see:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM debian:9
 ---> d508d16c64cd
Step 2/3 : COPY file.txt /root/file.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f06029c1cca
Step 3/3 : RUN rm -f /root/file.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2dc62c823c9
Successfully built a2dc62c823c9
Successfully tagged erikmd:latest
```

Each step in the build process is generating a new layer, **and** it is providing you with an image id representing an intermediate image that is the result of all the Dockerfile commands up to that point.  Given the about output, I can run:

```
$ docker run --rm 6f06029c1cca cat /root/file.txt
```

And see the contents of the file:

```
hello world
```

But what if I *didn't* just build the image?  In that case, I would start by using the `docker image inspect` command to look at the list of layers that comprise the image:

```
$ docker image inspect erikmd | jq '.[0].RootFS.Layers'
[
  "sha256:13d5529fd232cacdd8cd561148560e0bf5d65dbc1149faf0c68240985607c303",
  "sha256:41494b03ef195ce6db527bd68b89cbebdace66210b4c142e95f8553fcb0bf51e",
  "sha256:1948a4bd00b6f1712667bb2c68d1fe6eb60fbbcdf8bad62653208c23bf2602a5"
]
```

In the above, `jq` is just a tool for querying JSON data.  You could just visually inspect the output of `docker image inspect` for the same information if you don't happen to have `jq` handy.

Assuming a default Docker configuration using the `overlay2` storage driver, you will find these identifiers in `/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/*/diff`.  So, for example:

```
# grep -l 13d5529fd232cacdd8cd561148560e0bf5d65dbc1149faf0c68240985607c303 \
  /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/*/diff
/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/13d5529fd232cacdd8cd561148560e0bf5d65dbc1149faf0c68240985607c303/diff
```

This first layer is the `debian:9` image.  We can confirm that by running:

```
$ docker image inspect debian:9 | jq '.[0].RootFS.Layers'
[
  "sha256:13d5529fd232cacdd8cd561148560e0bf5d65dbc1149faf0c68240985607c303"
]
```

...so we'll ignore it.  Let's find the second layer:

```
# grep -l 41494b03ef195ce6db527bd68b89cbebdace66210b4c142e95f8553fcb0bf51e \
  /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/*/diff
/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/14347a192896a59fdf5c1a9ffcac2f93025433c66136d3531d7bbb3aec53efc7/diff
```

Inside the same directory as that `diff` file, we'll find a file called `cache-id`:

```
# cat image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/14347a192896a59fdf5c1a9ffcac2f93025433c66136d3531d7bbb3aec53efc7/cache-id
118b1e4a401873e1db8849c0821d0280b4cf9ef621ccb70cf14fe672dc74ef75
```

That `cache-id` identifies the directory into which the layer has been extracted; we can find it under `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<id>`:

```
# ls /var/lib/docker/overlay2/118b1e4a401873e1db8849c0821d0280b4cf9ef621ccb70cf14fe672dc74ef75
diff/ link lower work/
```

We're interested in the contents of the `diff/` directory:

```
# find /var/lib/docker/overlay2/118b1e4a401873e1db8849c0821d0280b4cf9ef6
21ccb70cf14fe672dc74ef75/diff/
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/118b1e4a401873e1db8849c0821d0280b4cf9ef621ccb70cf14fe672dc74ef75/diff/
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/118b1e4a401873e1db8849c0821d0280b4cf9ef621ccb70cf14fe672dc74ef75/diff/root
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/118b1e4a401873e1db8849c0821d0280b4cf9ef621ccb70cf14fe672dc74ef75/diff/root/file.txt
```

And there it is!

---

**NB** All of the above assumes that you're using the `overlay2` storage driver (which is the default on most if not all platforms these days). If you're using a different driver, the layout on disk is going to be different.

Comment: This is genius. Thank you for writing this tutorial! Also, for a shorthand way to find a specific file, knowing it's location from the Dockerfile, I ran `ls /var/lib/docker/overlay2/*/diff/removed-file.txt` and I was able to find the contents simply.